# Selenium 'get attribute' returns large string instead of ID

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the ID of a web element that contains the word 'Search'. After doing some research I got this:

```
elementid = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Search')]").__getattribute__("id")
```

The ID that should be returning is 'header-search-bar' but I get this: 1f7b49b1-1f8c-4a38-b466-a7eca3d2ff0b

What did I do wrong? What is the meaning of the string that is being returned?

Comment: We can't possibly know on what kind of input are you trying this. Can you append it to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

try to use get_attribute instead **getattribute**:

```
elementid = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Search')]").get_attribute("id")
```

Comment: I tried that but it returns an empty string.

Comment: @EvanMiller try .get_attribute('value')

Comment: @EvanMiller make screenshort of your element and it's value, please

Comment: ```<input class="gNO89b" value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" data-ved="0ahUKEwjCovmIzbrvAhWORjABHSTFBHAQ4dUDCA0">```

Comment: @EvanMiller so what attribute do want to get?

Comment: I would like to get the ID.

Comment: @EvanMiller seems like it's doesn't have an ID, only class, value, aria-label, name, type and data-ved

Comment: I see, so that is why it returned null. But how come when I get the value it's a long string instead of 'Google Search'?

Comment: @EvanMiller just double checked: print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Пошук Google']").get_attribute('value')), works perfect for me

Comment: That works fine for me too but I need to find the elements based off their text like my original code. The code you provided finds the elements based off their value.

Comment: @EvanMiller you need read about xpath, css selectors in official documentations

Comment: There is not 'header-search-bar' . Vova tried as he could.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about a different attribute - `data-ved`. There is no attribute `id`. Also, as I understand, you want to get text. Try the following:

```
your_attribute = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi").get_attribute("data-ved")
```

To get text:

```
yout_text = driver. find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi").text
```

Or

```
your_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi").get_attribute("value")
```